# union type giving error message after upgrading to typescript 3.2.2

Tags: typescript

I have the following types that are used for React components:

```
export interface AsyncRouteComponentState {
  Component: AsyncRouteableComponent | null;
}

export interface AsyncComponent {
  getInitialProps: (props: Ctx<any>) => any;
  load?: () => Promise<React.ReactNode>;
}

export interface AsyncRouteComponent<Props = {}>
  extends AsyncComponent,
    React.Component<DocumentProps & Props, AsyncRouteComponentState> {}

export type AsyncRouteComponentType<Props> =
  | React.ComponentClass<Props> & AsyncComponent
  | React.StatelessComponent<Props> & AsyncComponent;

export type AsyncRouteableComponent<Props = any> =
  | AsyncRouteComponentType<RouteComponentProps<Props>>
  | React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<Props>>
  | React.ComponentType<Props>;
```

I have the following component:

```
class AsyncRouteComponent extends React.Component<Props, AsyncRouteComponentState> {
    render() {
      const { Component: ComponentFromState } = this.state;

      if (ComponentFromState) {
        return <ComponentFromState {...this.props} />;
      }

      if (Placeholder) {
        return <Placeholder {...this.props} />;
      }

      return null;
    }
  };
}
```

It is complaining about the `return <ComponentFromState {...this.props} />;` in

```
  if (ComponentFromState) {
    return <ComponentFromState {...this.props} />;
  }
```

The error message is:

> Type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly' is
>   missing the following properties from type 'RouteComponentProps': history, location, match

There are no such type errors in typescript 3.1.x.

The component is of type:

```
export type AsyncRouteableComponent<Props = any> =
  | AsyncRouteComponentType<RouteComponentProps<Props>>
  | React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<Props>>
  | React.ComponentType<Props>;
```

Is it because I have not narrowed the union and it cannot tell if it needs a component with `RouteComponentProps`?

The whole point is that the component could or could not have these props.

I'm a bit stuck on how to fix this?

Comment: TypeScript is rightfully warning you that the `props` may not be exactly what `ComponentFromState` is ready to accept. `ComponentFromState` may be one of three things, but there is no certainty the provided props will match all three APIs.